# 'Unexpected Keyword Argument' in super().__init__()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a small text game. 
I keep getting an error when trying to define a class variable.

Here's the class code:

```
class Scenery():
    def __init__(self,name,description):
        self.name=name
        self.description=description

class Door(Scenery):
    def __init__(self,openstatus,lockstatus):
        self.openstatus=openstatus
        self.lockstatus=lockstatus
        super().__init__(name,description,openstatus,lockstatus)

class CageDoor(Door):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(lockstatus=False,
                         openstatus=False,
                         name="Cage Door",
                         description="It's the door to the cage.")
```

The main.py code:

```
from tiles import CageDoor

CageDoor = CageDoor()
```

And the error:

```
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    CageDoor = CageDoor()
  *File Location*
    name="Cage Door"
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Answer (score 11):

`Door`'s `__init__` doesn't accept `name` or `description`, so the call in `CageDoor.__init__` (which passes control to `Door.__init__` because `super()` determines that is the next class up in the inheritance hierarchy) is going to fail.

Change `Door.__init__` to:

```
class Door(Scenery):
    def __init__(self,openstatus,lockstatus, *args, **kwargs):
        self.openstatus=openstatus
        self.lockstatus=lockstatus
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and it will then seamlessly pass along all arguments besides the two it uses to the next `__init__` up the chain. The advantage to accepting and passing `*args` and `**kwargs` is that even if `Scenery`'s constructor prototype changes, `Door` doesn't have to; the callers would need to pass along the correct arguments if no defaults are provided (so adding new arguments to `Scenery`'s constructor without giving them useful defaults is poor form), but `Door` remains stable.

Comment: This fixed my problem pretty quickly but the same problem occurred and the use of **kwargs did not help:

`class BaseTile():
 def __init__(self,x,y,*args,**kwargs):
  self.x=x
  self.y=y

class DoorTile(BaseTile):
 def __init__(self,door,):
  self.door=door
  super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

class NWBasement(DoorTile):
 def __init__(self):
  super().__init__(x=0,y=0,door=CageDoor())

NWBasementTile = NWBasement()
`

`
  File "tiles.py", line 25, in __init__
    super().__init__(x=0,y=0,door=CageDoor())
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
`

Comment: @ContortedTrash: `DoorTile` is passing `*args,**kwargs` but not accepting them. You can't pass stuff without accepting it!

Answer (score 3):

When using super it is important that all the methods in the call chain use the same interface. Here you have `Door` not taking `name`, or `description`. And Scenery doesn't take `openstatus` or `lockstatus`. You should have every method in the call chain accept `*args`, and `**kwargs` so it can ignore parameters it doesn't care about. For more information see [this post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

In this example it means re-writing `Door` and `Scenery` thusly:

```
class Scenery():
    def __init__(self,name,description, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name=name
        self.description=description

class Door(Scenery):
    def __init__(self openstatus,lockstatus, *args, **kwargs):
        self.openstatus=openstatus
        self.lockstatus=lockstatus
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: For the top of the hierarchy, assuming no multiple inheritance (which is usually a good idea to avoid, and since `Scenery` doesn't delegate using `super`, it's assuming that already), you wouldn't need to accept `*args, **kwargs`, since the top of the hierarchy isn't going to pass them anywhere else, and having completely unrecognized arguments raise an exception helps avoid issues with typo-ed keyword argument names getting silently dropped on the floor.